# How to listen to one port and reverse proxy to several ports in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been able to make a reverse proxy using Nginx to redirect POST requests made to the 8080 port to the 8081 port.
Now, I would like to redirect them to the 8082 additionally.

```
events {}

http {
        server {
                listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
                }
                location /api/ {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
                }
        }
}
```

But by doing this, I'm only receiving the requests on the 8081 port, and not on the 8082 with the /api endpoint.
Also, I would like to not use any endpoint ( / ) on both reverse proxy configuration if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the server listening on port `8082` actually *is* receiving the traffic, but you're getting an error because the proxy is requesting `/api/` rather than `/`, since it's literally just forwarding the request. If this actually is the problem, rewriting the request before passing it off via the proxy should do the trick.

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
        }
        location /api/ {
            rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not really sure what you mean by your last sentence. Do you mean that you want the api endpoint to be reachable via the base URI as well?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunaltely, it doesn't work.
I was chatting with somebody on Discord who told be that it wasn't possible, that HTTP couldn't do that and was only handling one request and one response at a time.
So what he advised me to do, was to send several requests using multithreading, and it works well. Thanks !